# AppleMetalGLRenderer Crash

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I am trying to figure out what is causing this crash and so far have been unable to determine what the problem is.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  This is the log from Firebase on the crash, and its happened multiple times.

```
Crashed: WebThread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x00000000000048e8
0
AGXMetalA11
(Missing)
1
AppleMetalGLRenderer
GLDContextRec::setRenderTexturesAndSamplersInternal(unsigned int, unsigned int&, SetSamplerStateIMPCache*, SetTextureIMPCache*)
2
AppleMetalGLRenderer
GLDContextRec::setRenderTexturesAndSamplersInternal(unsigned int, unsigned int&, SetSamplerStateIMPCache*, SetTextureIMPCache*)
3
AppleMetalGLRenderer
GLDContextRec::setRenderSamplersAndTextures()
4
AppleMetalGLRenderer
GLDContextRec::setRenderState(unsigned int)
5
AppleMetalGLRenderer
gldRenderVertexArray(GLDContextRec*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, unsigned int, void const*, int, void const*)
6
GLEngine
glDrawElements_ACC_ES2Exec
7
WebCore
WebCore::GraphicsContext3D::drawElements(unsigned int, int, unsigned int, long) + 64
8
WebCore
WebCore::WebGLRenderingContextBase::drawElements(unsigned int, int, unsigned int, long long) + 316
9
WebCore
WebCore::jsWebGLRenderingContextPrototypeFunctionDrawElements(JSC::ExecState*) + 328
10
JavaScriptCore
llint_entry + 135068
11
JavaScriptCore
llint_entry + 124496
12
JavaScriptCore
llint_entry + 124496
13
JavaScriptCore
llint_entry + 124496
14
JavaScriptCore
llint_entry + 124496
15
JavaScriptCore
llint_entry + 124664
16
JavaScriptCore
llint_entry + 124664
17
JavaScriptCore
llint_entry + 124496
18
JavaScriptCore
llint_entry + 124664
19
JavaScriptCore
llint_entry + 124496
20
JavaScriptCore
llint_entry + 124496
21
JavaScriptCore
llint_entry + 124496
22
JavaScriptCore
llint_entry + 124496
23
JavaScriptCore
llint_entry + 129852
24
JavaScriptCore
llint_entry + 124496
25
JavaScriptCore
llint_entry + 124496
26
JavaScriptCore
vmEntryToJavaScript + 248
27
JavaScriptCore
JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 408
28
JavaScriptCore
JSC::profiledCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::ProfilingReason, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&, WTF::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&) + 196
29
WebCore
WebCore::JSExecState::profiledCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::ProfilingReason, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&, WTF::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&) + 140
30
WebCore
WebCore::JSCallbackData::invokeCallback(WebCore::JSDOMGlobalObject&, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::MarkedArgumentBuffer&, WebCore::JSCallbackData::CallbackType, JSC::PropertyName, WTF::NakedPtr<JSC::Exception>&) + 356
31
WebCore
WebCore::JSRequestAnimationFrameCallback::handleEvent(double) + 412
32
WebCore
WebCore::ScriptedAnimationController::serviceRequestAnimationFrameCallbacks(double) + 400
33
WebCore
WebCore::Page::updateRendering() + 280
34
WebKitLegacy
LayerFlushController::flushLayers() + 52
35
WebKitLegacy
WebViewLayerFlushScheduler::layerFlushCallback() + 56
36
CoreFoundation
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
37
CoreFoundation
__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 416
38
CoreFoundation
CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 496
39
WebCore
RunWebThread(void*) + 612
40
libsystem_pthread.dylib
_pthread_start + 156
41
libsystem_pthread.dylib
thread_start + 8
```

I am not sure why its reporting java because we are not using java in this app; I can only assume Apple has something running in the background.  Also, We are not using AppleMetalGLRenderer specifically so again I'm assuming that Apple has it on by default?

Any help would be appreciated.